# Plotting years with decimals in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting years across two decades using ggplot.I have a situation where due to how the data for the years was taken, the datapoints are really halfway through the year so to be accurate, I labeled the years with a .5 at the end. In addition, I also have one single datapoint that was taken in early 2005 so it's labeled as `2005.22` so the years look like : `2005.22, 2005.5,2006.5,2007.5,2008.5,2009.5,2010.5,2011.5,2012.5`. Since I am technically missing data for 2005-2005.21, I want the plot to start at 2005 with no line showing until 2005.22 and then breaking every 2 years starting at 2005.5,2007.5 and so on...
I've been using the following to plot `geom_line` for the years but I do not know how to get the above result. I was able to get the limits to start at 2005 but with the datapoint starting at 2005.22, it just plots like 2005.22,2007.22....below is what I am using to properly plot and break the years.

````
scale_x_continuous(
      name = "year",
      breaks = seq(c(2005, 2012.5), by=2),
      expand = c(0,0))+
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(2005, 2012.5))```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard for me to understand what exactly you want the plot to look like (especially in terms of the labels), but does this do what you're looking for? You can add 2005 to the front of the breaks sequence, which places it in front without disrupting the rest of the sequence.

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(x=c(2005.22, 2005.5,2006.5,2007.5,2008.5,2009.5,2010.5,2011.5,2012.5), 
                y=runif(9,-1,1))

ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2005, seq(2005.5, 2012.5,2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for. It works but for some reason the year labels do not plot. Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Are you running the same code as above or something modified? Does anything plot for x-axis labels, or they're just blank? I can't think of any reason why if you're running the code exactly as above nothing would plot. If you have different labels you want to see, I can edit the above to show how you might achieve that.